# ServiceStack IAuthSession blank after login

Tags: c#, servicestack

So, I run debug on `localhost/auth/credential` with auth feature, and successfully logged in with `user=admin, pass=pass, rememberMe=true`. I got a Json response `UserName=admin, SessionId=1`, so far so good.

Then I have a `SessionService` to check my current Session:

```
[Route("user/session")]
public class Session {
}
public class SessionResponse { 
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
class SessionService : Service {
    public dynamic Get(Session req) {
        IAuthSession session = this.GetSession();
        return new SessionResponse() {
            SessionId = session.Id,
            UserName = session.UserName,
        };
    }
}
```

But when I go visit :

`localhost/user/session`

I got **SessionId = K16UMnr2eBXiIFUwAod, UserName = null** where I expected UserName=admin. I am stuck with this for hours, can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help?

**UPDATE ==============================================================**

When I login, browser received:

```
X-UAId=1
```

then browser sent:

```
ss-pid=zV7OOe2sP8hwlo8rR0EZ
ss-id=K16UMnr2eBXiIFUwAod
X-UAId=1
```

as the picture shows:

**URL: localhost/auth/credentials?format=json**

[image]

Then I visit the session service:

**URL: localhost/user/session**

[image]

As you can see, I am picking up the ss-id as SessionId. I am logged in with admin, **UserName=admin** is expected, but I got **UserName=null**. Why is it?

[image]

Comment: Probably a silly question, but did you configure the [cache client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching)?  I'm not sure if it is required since I always have it in my SS apps.

Comment: Are you using a browser or something like Fiddler/REST Console to make requests to the URLs? It doesn't appear the request to http://localhost:2000/user/session has the session cookie from your request to /auth/credential persisted in your cache.

Comment: @Eli Gassert, Yes. container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemcachedClientCache(new [] { "127.0.0.0:11211" }));

Comment: @paaschpa, I am using FireFox+FireBug. was running debug in localhost:2000 in VS2012, now deployed to localhost on IIS.

Comment: I think this is not the problem, but try to change from public dynamic Get(Session req) to public SessionResponse Get(Session req). Maybe the Json Serializer is messing things.

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto, just tried as you suggested, no difference. Actually session is already blank with everything null before being returned. Only Id is session id, but email, name...are all missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!!

Thank Eli Gassert. Following his hint, I suspect the **MemcachedClient** wasn't setup properly. So I switched it to simple **MemoryCacheClient**.

Everything instantly works properly now. Because MemcachedClient wasn't remembering anything. So there was no session at all.

Comment: I have a similar situation but using the FacebookAuthProvider, I've added the MemoryCacheClient to the app host configuration but is still not working for me, do you have any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200419/servicestack-iauthsession-empty-after-authentication-with-facebookauthprovider