# ServiceStack IAuthSession empty after authentication with FacebookAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to get the user data through IAuthSession after a doing an authentication with facebook, when I try get the user with **Request.GetSession(true)** which returns AuthUserSession (implements IAuthSession) I get a partial subset of data like the following:

[image: IAuthSession]

I'm trying to use it in a service method

```
[ClientCanSwapTemplates]
        [DefaultView("dashboard")]
        public DashboardResponse Get(FacebookRequest userRequest)
        {
            var user1 = Request.GetSession(true);
            return new DashboardResponse();

        }
```

I've added the auth providers my apphost as follows:

```
 Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
                new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new BasicAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new LinkedInAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new CredentialsAuthProvider()
            }));
```

As far as I know the [facebookAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/FacebookAuthProvider.cs#L90) should fill the IAuthSession with the following information:

```
userSession.FacebookUserId = tokens.UserId ?? userSession.FacebookUserId;
userSession.FacebookUserName = tokens.UserName ?? userSession.FacebookUserName;
userSession.DisplayName = tokens.DisplayName ?? userSession.DisplayName;
userSession.FirstName = tokens.FirstName ?? userSession.FirstName;
userSession.LastName = tokens.LastName ?? userSession.LastName;
userSession.PrimaryEmail = tokens.Email ?? userSession.PrimaryEmail ?? userSession.Email;
```

what step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in a similar situation like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756797/servicestack-iauthsession-blank-after-login/15776234#comment26708873_15776234) based the answer I decided to try that out, and It worked.

the only difference is that I'm using simple injector and you have to consider to register that dependency as [Singleton](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#Singleton) the easier way for me to register it was this:

```
simpleInjectorContainer.RegisterSingle<ICacheClient>(()=>new MemoryCacheClient());
```